# Regex not substituting file name

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I am trying to run this command from a script and it seems that it fails to match the value of regex.

```
cat /config.yml_orig >> /build/Product*/config.yml
```

And it fails with

```
/build/Product*/config.yml: No such file or directory
```

The product number of the directory keeps on changing so I have substituted with `*` but on command line it fails to match the regex for this.

What is the solution for this when the commands fails to identify its a regex.

Comment: Shell uses wildcards (AKA "globs"), not regular expressions.

Comment: Is it possible for there to be multiple directories that will match `/build/Product*`? If so, your strategy and the current answers will break in fun and exciting ways when there are multiple directories matching that pattern

Answer (score 1):

A wildcard will only match an existing file, so you can't use it if you're creating the file. You need to get the directory separately with a wildcard, then append the filename:

```
dir=$(echo /build/Product*)
cat config.yml_orig >> "$dir"/config.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is trying to match the whole thing, and it's failing if the "config.yml" file doesn't exist. Try:

```
cat config.yml_orig >> "$(echo /build/Product*)"/config.yml
```